Approximating characteristic functions by continuous function (without Urysohn's lemma)
Let $\mathbb T\subseteq \mathbb C$ be the torus equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Haar measure $\mu$. Let $I\subseteq \mathbb T$ be a compact and connected set and $\chi_I$ denote the characteristic function of $I$.

Show that for each $\epsilon>0$, there exist continuous functions $f,g$ on $\mathbb T$ such that $f \le \chi_I\le g$ and $\int_{\mathbb T}(g-f)\ d\mu<\epsilon$.

My attempt: I can show the result using Urysohn's lemma but I'm interested whether one can find concrete piecewise linear approximation of $\chi_I$?
